# OWL: what is the difference between non-negative integer and positive integer?

Tags: semantics, semantic-web, owl, ontology, protege

I am trying to use Protégé to build my OWL ontology

Whilst building some data properties, I found that OWL has two types: `non negative integer` and `positive integer`: what is the difference between them?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

They come from [XML Schema](http://www.w3.org/TR/xmlschema-2/):

**Positive Integer**

> positiveInteger is ·derived· from nonNegativeInteger by setting the value of ·minInclusive· to be 1. This results in the standard mathematical concept of the positive integer numbers. The ·value space· of positiveInteger is the infinite set {1,2,...}. The ·base type· of positiveInteger is nonNegativeInteger.

**Non-Negative Integer**

> nonNegativeInteger is ·derived· from integer by setting the value of ·minInclusive· to be 0. This results in the standard mathematical concept of the non-negative integers. The ·value space· of nonNegativeInteger is the infinite set {0,1,2,...}. The ·base type· of nonNegativeInteger is integer.